# How to save or update multiple values in database using jdbctemplate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have multiple records to insert. But that records may contain duplicate values or database may have same values as those records. My question is how to check that the current insertion is duplicate one. is there  any way to update the existing data while inserting like saveorupdate in hibernate ? I am using JdbcTemplate of spring.

eg.

Records to be inserted:

```
Name  Phone
A     111
B     222
A     333
```

Table:

```
ID(auto)  Name  Phone(unique)
1          C     111          //here update
2          D     888
3  //here insert new data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update multiple table together,procedures could help.
Also, to update multiple rows, its better to update one row at a time i.e. using some statement to find whether the exist and later firing query.
To find that simply make an search query over its unique id , if value is not null, proceed with execute update [usage refernece](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzaha/stateex.htm).

Comment: Naren I have required to insert the new data and if old data with constraints are there then it will update only. I have given the example above. kindly look at it.

Comment: I believe there will be two db hits then..(1)to know if the element persist (2) Later to update or insert a new record if it isn't persist. For more refernce executeQuery()---for getting the data from database 
executeUpdate()---for insert,update,delete 
execute()-any kind of operations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with it.

```
public void insert(ModelName modelName){
        //condition to check if Phone is an existent row

        String sql = "INSERT INTO modelName" +
            "(ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { modelName.getId(),
            modelName.getName() 
        });

}
```